# What does the implementation of keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy look like?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I found **tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy** is an amazing class that helps me create a loss function for a neural network that has a large number of output classes. Without this it is impossible to train the model, as I found **tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy** gave an out-of-memory error because of converting an index into a 1-hot vector of very large size.

I, however, have a problem of understanding how **sparse_categorical_crossentropy** avoids the big memory issue. I took a look at the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3b33c87378832a3a54717ecdf76b40b121345e9b/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L3402) from TF but it is indeed not easy to know what goes under the hood.

So, could anyone give some high-level idea of implementing this? What does the implementation look like? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not do anything special, it just produces the one-hot encoded labels inside the loss for a batch of data (not all data at the same time), when it is needed, and then discards the results. So its just a classic trade-off between memory and computation.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. Could you also take a look at Daniel's answer as below? He gave a completely different one to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for categorical crossentropy is the following:

[image]

Where `y_true` is the ground truth data and `y_pred` is your model's predictions.

The bigger the dimensions of `y_true` and `y_pred`, more memory is necessary to perform all these operations.

But notice an interesting trick in this formula: only one of the neurons in `y_true` is 1, all the rest are zeros!!! This means we can assume that only one term in the sum is non-zero.

What a sparse formula does is:

- Avoid the need to have a huge matrix for `y_true`, using only indices instead of one-hot encoding
- Pick from `y_pred` only the column respective to the index, instead of performing calculations for the entire tensor.

So, the main idea of a sparse formula here is:

- Gather columns from `y_pred` with the indices in `y_true`.
- Calculate only the term `-ln(y_pred_selected_columns)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your answer is completely opposite to @Matias Valdenegro's answer. Which one is correct? ...

Comment: @user1953737 I do not agree that this answer is opposite, its complementary as it provides more detail.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro: Following your answer, I think what it does is convert a batch of target idxs into a batch of 1 hot vectors. Following Daniel's answer, I think what he meant is using something like tf.gather_nd or so. I am thus confused which one is truly what tf does. Thx.

Comment: As far as I understood, categorical crossentropy can be used for a multi-label problem, but sparse categorical crossentropy cannot. I am wondering how to deal with a case in which we have e.g. 10,000 possible output classes and each input belongt to e.g. 3 classes. Here we need to provide a output vector with 3 times a 1 (or 0.33) and 9,997 times a 0?

Comment: @ChristianWartena, you need an output vector of size 10000 containing 3 times 1. You need to use "sigmoid" with "binary crossentropy".