# Tensorflow with Keras: sparse_categorical_crossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new on StackOverflow and I also recently started to work with Tensorflow and Keras. Currently I'm developing an architecture using LSTM units. My question was partially discussed here:

[What does the implementation of keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59577258/11998355)

However, in my model I have a predicted tensor, **y_hat**, of size (batch_size, seq_length, vocabulary_dimension) and the true labels, **y**, of size (batch_size, seq_length).

I would like to know how the value of the loss is computed when I call
**loss = sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y,y_hat)**: how does the sparse_crossentropy function calculate the loss value starting from two tensors of different dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

The [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) is a way to compare two probability distributions. That is, it says how different or similar the two are. It is a mathematical function defined on two arrays or continuous distributions as [shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Definition).

The 'sparse' part in 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' indicates that the y_true value must have a single value per row, e.g. `[0, 2, ...]` that indicates which outcome (category) was the right choice. The model then outputs the `y_pred` that must be like `[[.99, .01, 0], [.01, .5, .49], ...]`. Here, model predicts that the 0th category has a chance of .99 in the first row. This is very close to the true value, that is `[1,0,0]`. The `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` would then calculate a single number with two distributions using the above mentioned formula and return that number.

If you used a 'categorical_crossentropy' it would expect the `y_true` to be a one-hot encoded vector, like `[[0,0,1], [0,1,0], ...]`.

If you would like to know the details in depth, you can take a look at the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/23ddb02643654685f839e17a2ce72916775e5fe5/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L1534).

Comment: Let me see if I inderstood correctly. Suppose I have: y_true = [2,4,5,1]  with each entry corresponding to a class. y_pred=[[0.99, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0], [0.2 ,0.7, 0.05, 0.05], [0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2] ,[0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.9] ]. Does this mean that the best prediction is y_pred=[2,4,4,1]?

Comment: The perfect prediction would be like this `[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], ...]` if the `y_true = [2,4, ...]` is given. Because the y_pred must have the biggest value at the index which is given in y_true. so, if y_true says '3', you should predict [[0,0,0,1,0],].

Comment: Ok, about the "ideal", "perfect" prediction that you mentioned, I agree with you: in that case we would have loss_function(y_true, y_pred) = 0. But what if I have a predicted vector like in my example (which is not the ideal prediction!): is it correct to say, in that specific case, that the model would predict the vector y_pred=[2,4,4,1]? Therefore generating a loss value given by loss_func(y_true, y_pred) !=0?

Comment: If model is predicting y_pred=[[0.99, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0], [0.2 ,0.7, 0.05, 0.05], [0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2] ,[0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.9] ]. Then no, your model is trying to predict [0, 1, 1, 3], not [2,4,4,1]. If it's still unclear, I can make another example for you.

Comment: Perfectly clear now. I was just thinking about my specific application and getting confused: I meant exactly what you were trying to explain me before. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Sorry again but what happens if the number of classes is not equal to the length of the y vectors? For esample: I have 10 classes but the y_true vector is as above with dimensions (1,4). But in this case I would have y_pred of dimentions (1,4,10).. how can I now compare y_pred and y_true. An example of this would be super useful!!!

Comment: You just have to use sparse_categorical_crossentropy. If you pass correct dimensions, it will automatically return correct results. For example, if you have y_true of dimensions [N, 1] and N is number of examples in dataset, you must have y_pred like [N, M] where M is categories, N is number of examples. If you can show me the code, I could help more.